# BASH getopts OPTARG undefined

Tags: bash

I have this code, and when I call it in command line, it shows the echo in option/the one I have in each option/ but $OPTARG is undefined. And  I have no idea why.

```
   OPTIND=1
    optm=
    optl=
    while getopts "ml:" opt
    do
    case "$opt" in
    m)
    optm=$OPTARG
    echo "m was triggered"
    ;;
    l)
    moznostl=$OPTARG
echo "l was triggered"
    ;;
   esac
   done
   shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
```

and my second question is:
`OPTIND=2`
can this be used to start with second argument? I mean it works but wheater it is legit way to do that. for example:

```
./project first -l second
```

so it would skip the first agument and started with -l?

Comment: I would usually store the first argument in a variable, then shift. That way I don't tinker around with the value of `OPTIND`. Furthermore, is there a reason why you do `optm=$OPTARG`? According to `getopts "ml:"`, the `-m` flag does not take any parameter. Apart from that, I don't think I understood your question; the slashes are quite confusing: *which* echo does it show? How do you see that `$OPTARG` is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You've got this line

```
while getopts "ml:" opt
```

This tells the shell that `m` may exist but takes no parameter, and that `l` may appear with exactly one parameter.

I suspect you meant to use `getopts 'm:l' opt`.

Comment: Just noticed @ayekat has alluded to the same issue. Kudos there.